# Failover IP when server on DNS supplied IP fails iOS

Tags: ios, dns, failover, amazon-route53

My iOS app uses a single hard-code URL `api.xyz.com` to find our REST service. At the moment there are just two servers running this service, and we use [Amazon Route 53 DNS](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/). But I've found that the timeout of an hour (or more) is too long incase one of our servers fails; don't want to leave users in the dark that long.

The alternative would be to implement a failover mechanism in the app. To be honest, I don't like the idea of pulling this low level DNS-related logic in the app, but I don't see another solution at the moment.

So my question is: How do I implement such a failover mechanism on iOS?  I'm using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for my REST API.

Or, are there better alternatives on server side? At the moment the servers are individually rented ones, so no Amazon, Google, ... cloud service.

Comment: The best solution is to use some sort of load-balanced or fail-over cloud services so that your servers appear as a single server. This way the app doesn't ned to worry about failover at all

Comment: Which "timeout of an hour (or more)" are you referring to?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it seems that many DNS kindly ignore the 60s TTL specified by Route53, and it seems they often take an hour as minimum.

Comment: I see.  So it's not an explicit or configured timeout.  You're saying that in spite of your short configured TTL, you've confirmed that Route 53 is correctly updating the DNS yet the app is not able to actually see the changes to the DNS in a timely fashion.